# Mineral Hardness Scales

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

I am doing research into lunar regolith's hardness in relation to abrasion of lunar tools and need to choose a hardness scale (either Mohs, or Rockwell A, B, or C). Is either of these metrics more legitimate/accurate than the other?

Comment: Mohs is defiantly not metrics it is more a qualitative scale rather a quantitative, Rockwel and Vickers are among the standard tests, also Brinell, but i'm not sure if Rockwell is appropriate to test thin specimens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rockwell,Brinell, Knoop, Vickers, etc are for materials like metals that have at least a little ductility as the rely on plastic deformation. Mohs is for brittle minerals although it is somewhat qualitative. Abrasion of tools is not that simple anyway. For example : aluminum is softer than many metals but aluminum castings are very abrasive to cutting tools as the high silicon content combines with the aluminum to make hard abrasive particles in the soft matrix.